# SQL Server 2005 doing full table Sort before Index Scan

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I'm having a problem with ordering performance in my SQL Server 2005 database.
Lets say I have the following query:

```
select 
    id, versionId, orderIndex
from Forms_Page
where
    versionId = 'AFCF4921-31B4-44C1-B3A7-913910F7600E'
order by
    orderIndex
```

This query will return 7 rows and take ~23 seconds to execute. The execution plan of this query is as follows (can't post images yet):

**select (cost: 0%) -> Sort (cost: 11%) -> Clustered Index Scan (cost: 89%)**

If I remove the 'order by' clause, the query will complete in ~4 ms, like expected.

Why is the SQL Server doing a sort before getting the requested rows? It doesn't make sense to me. Why not getting the 7 rows first and sorting only those? Am I missing something, like a database configuration, or is this an expected behavior?

I could use an inner select, like the below, to force the engine to get the rows first and then order, which would return the rows in ~6 ms, but since we are using the EF this wouldn't be a good solution for us (we could sort the results in memory, but we are using LoadWith options for some of the entities that generate SQL code with sorts, and that code is also suffering from the same 'order by' problem).

```
select *
from(
    select 
        id, versionId, orderIndex
    from Forms_Page
    where
        versionId = 'AFCF4921-31B4-44C1-B3A7-913910F7600E'
) T
order by
    T.orderIndex
```

I have tested some indexing is the sorted columns, which fastened thing, but only because the columns are already sorted. Seems like a clunky solution...

Comment: The order of the steps Clustered Index Scan -> Sort -> Select. The Select what you see is the last step, which exactly gives the expected output. (and the output should be sorted) And in the plan the "bigger task" estimated is the index scan and not the sort. Are you sure, that without the order by the execution plan uses the same index to scan?

Comment: Yes, it uses the same index because it but something I realized, now that you mentioned, is that for a simple search it uses IMPLICIT_CONVERT to convert the string to a unique identifier while in the order by it's using {guid, 'AFCF4921-31B4-44C1-B3A7-913910F7600E'}.

I made some tests with casts and converts and I keep getting the same times.

Comment: Is VersionId a Unique Key? Or can you have duplicates? If it's unique I would expect this to be a lot faster.

Comment: This column can have duplicates since it's a foreign key to another table in a 1 to N relation.
The previous designers opted to use guids as a primary key (id field), but the natural PK of this table would be something along the lines of (versionID, orderIndex). I created an index for this (seems someone forgot) and now the sort is fast due to Index Seek but I'm still having problems if I query for some field without an index (that would return in ms) and then sort the result (taking around 25 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't know why it's doing it! Having said that, here are a couple of things you have possibly already tried.

- Query Hints:
  Have you tried using any of the various query hints documented here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx. In particular the `RECOMPILE` option.
- What about the usual steps of [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) and [DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx)? These are the things I usually try.
- Update statistics: Either by running `UPDATE STATISTICS tablename` or `EXEC sp_updatestats` to update stats for the whole database.

Finally, and perhaps not relevant in your case, but there's a good explanation of table hints here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/19/sql-server-understanding-table-hints-with-examples/

Comment: Sadly, none of those worked and even with HINTS, I don't think it's possible to tell the Entity Framework to use them, as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: This is extremely strange!
I just rerun EXEC sp_updatestats and not it works fine. It's strange that it didn't worked the first time! But what matters it's working now!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's bizarre, but cool that it eventually worked out okay. I will make a note to update stats twice if it doesn't seem to work the first time ;-)